NIST-800-22 input data format
I would like to make sure on how to set input data correctly for . Im testing some random generators. The Generator outputs a random number in decimal (for example 103), I convert it to binary (01100111 in our example). Now in NIST-800-22 should I input data converted like that as ASCII Input or binary input? If Im not understanding correctly, how should I change the data to ASCII correctly?

The question states:

The Generator outputs a random number in decimal (for example 103), I convert it to binary (01100111 in our example).

That conversion is appropriate if and only if the random number generated could be in range $[0,255]$. I'll assume that.
Quoting NIST's SP 800-22a §5.4.1

If the user has a stand-alone program or hardware device which implements a RNG, the user may want to construct as many files of arbitrary length as desired. Files should contain binary sequences stored as either ASCII characters consisting of zeroes and ones, or as binary data where each byte contains eight bits worth of 0’s and 1’s. The NIST Statistical Test Suite can then independently examine these files.

So if the ASCII format is used, then each random number should be encoded as 8 characters in the file, with each character represented as a byte with hexadecimal value 30h (48) for 0 or 31h (49) for 1. The bits of a given byte should be consecutive, and in big-endian order (01100111 in the example).
If the binary format is used, then each random number should be encoded as a single byte: 67h (107) in the example. Beware that no substitution should occur when writing the file. In particular the byte 0Ah (10) must not be converted to two bytes 0Dh (13) and 0Ah (10), as could occur with a file output in text mode under some OS.
Notice some SP 800-22a tests need many input bits, e.g. 106 or more. Such files will be 1 MByte or more in ASCII format, 125kByte or more in binary format. If the test is re-run, more files must be generated.

Caution: That a Random Number Generator passes SP 800-22a is not a good indication that the RNG is suitable for cryptographic use. It's easy to make, deliberately or accidentally, a RNG that passes SP 800-22a and is very vulnerable to attack, in particular by an adversary knowing the RNG's actual nature. SP 800-22a is good mostly to

Prove that an implementation of a RNG is badly defective, when the test fails (significantly more often than predicted). When the test succeeds, we do not learn that the RNG is not badly defective, much less that the RNG is secure.
Catch some implementation mistakes in a PRNG, or a RNG post-conditionning.
Give confidence in a true RNG source with light pre-conditionning (e.g. bits are generated by timing the delays between generation of alpha particles, grouping these delays in pairs, and outputing 0 or 1 depending on if the second delay is smaller or larger than the first).

SP 800-22a (and any statistical test of the output of a RNG) stinks at
detecting that the randomness source of a heavily conditioned TRNG is defective, or that a PRNG or post-conditioner has no cryptographic security.

I simply tell everybody to generate binary (0-255) byte files. It's simpler, clearer and if that's too hard for the poster, they shouldn't be making RNGs.
